# Where is en_core_web_sm of Python2 for spacy in Python3?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science, spacy

I need to repeat an experiment. The experiment was conducted in python 2.7 and spacy 1.8.2. The following [snippet](https://github.com/kohpangwei/influence-release/blob/0f656964867da6ddcca16c14b3e4f0eef38a7472/influence/nlprocessor.py#L28) give different outputs:

```
for raw_doc in spam + ham:
    doc = self.nlp(raw_doc)
    docs.append(' '.join(
        [token.lemma_ for token in doc if (token.is_alpha and not (token.is_oov or token.is_stop))]))
```

In the Python 3.7 environment, the `token.is_oov` is always `True`, which leads to empty selection. While spacy 1.8.2 gives reasonable result. The vocabulary is important here for identical repeat.

**Now I would like to repeat the experiment in python 3.7 and spacy 2.3**. What can I do now please?

---

I have to admit my question is not well proposed. I made mistakes in installation of the language package of spacy.The link (https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models) is a good reference.

Comment: Why this question receives downvotes? There are no comments about how shall I improve it or why it is bad question. I am really asking for HELP!!!

Comment: What are you actually trying to replicate? The output from `len(nlp.vocab.strings)` is not an informative number.

Comment: @aab I am trying to replicate the codes from (https://github.com/kohpangwei/influence-release/blob/0f656964867da6ddcca16c14b3e4f0eef38a7472/influence/nlprocessor.py#L28) to higher Python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the older version of the en_core_web_sm model 1.2.0 which was used with older spacy lib from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models
All the old spacy models and en_core..models are archived there.

Answer (score 0):

In the environment of interest try:

```
import en_core_web_sm
en_core_web_sm.__file__
```

Comment: Hi, it prints out `/workspace/miniconda3/envs/influence/lib/python3.7/site-packages/en_core_web_sm/__init__.py`. And the size is 1160 in python3's environment.

Comment: This means in Python 3.7 your `en_core_web_sm` package is at the above location

Comment: As you see, the size of `en_core_web_sm` in Python 3.7 is much smaller than that in Python 2.7. In order to repeat my experiment, I need to find the same size vocabulary in Python 3.7. I don't know how does it relate to the location of package.

Comment: @Tengerye >>>  `Where is en_core_web_sm of Python2 for spacy in Python3?` Did it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. But I think you misunderstood my question. I need something in Python 3 which can do the same thing as in Python 2.

Comment: @Tengerye What could be another option to answer a question `Where is?` than telling you the location where is your package?

Comment: But the file has much fewer vocabulary, only few thousand, in Python 3. The packages in Python2 and Python3 are different (although with the same name) I think.

Comment: Apologize if my question was confusing. I am in despair to get help to repeat the experiment.

Comment: @Tengerye What is your OS? What is your package manager, pip, conda? How did you create env for Python 2 and Python 3?

Comment: My OS is Linux. My package manager is pip.